# How to export each new list in a new column in the same csv file

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I started learning Python last week, and I'm writing a script in Python using bs4 in which I loop through a lot of lists b and each time I print this list in a csv files with this code:

```
with open('mairies.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for i in b:
            writer.writerows([[i]])
```

but it writes all the lists in the same column, and I need each list in a new one. Everywhere I look on the internet I'm told to use panda, which I don't want to. Do I need to start using panda or is there a solution I'm not seeing  in the csv doc?

Comment: post your `b` list and the expected csv result at the end

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! try removing the `for` loop and just put `writer.writerows(b)`

Comment: Can you post a small sample `b`? You say you "a lot of lists b"... so this code is being called by something else that generates more lists in `b`? In your example, is `i` a single value or a list? If there are lots of `b`'s and you want each to be a column, you may need to get them all into a larger list and then use `zip` to write the rows.

Comment: It sounds like you have a csv, but you want all of the rows to be columns. Basically pivot the table.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

No need of for loop

```
with open('mairies.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerows(b)
```

It is expected that `b` looks like a list of rows.

For example

```
b = [
  ['row1 item1', 'row1 item2', ..... ],
  ['row2 item1', 'row2 item2', ..... ],
]
```